# Where should I place modules settings, in /etc/modprobe.d or /lib/modprobe.d?

Tags: linux, modprobe, etc

My `man modprobe.d` says the following:

```
NAME
       modprobe.d - Configuration directory for modprobe

SYNOPSIS
       /lib/modprobe.d/*.conf

       /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf

       /run/modprobe.d/*.conf
```

What is the purpose of each of these folders?

I have only seen [this page](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=873220#c2) where somebody had a problem (in Red Hat) and had to move a configuration file from */etc* to */lib* because the former wasn't available in the [*initramfs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk):

> The /etc/modprobe.d directory isn't available in the initramfs, so the initramfsblacklist.conf isn't created and the rd.driver.blacklist isn't honored.
>
> Changing from /etc/modprobe.d to /lib/modprobe.d/ here restore the module blacklist behavior.

---

As an example, this is what I have in a new droplet in [DigitalOcean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean) with [Ubuntu 17.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_17.10_.28Artful_Aardvark.29) (Artful Aardvark):

```
ls -l /lib/modprobe.d/
```

Output:

```
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  655 Aug 15  2017 aliases.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1461 Mar 14 07:38 blacklist_linux_4.13.0-38-generic.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  390 Feb 20 12:50 fbdev-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  668 Feb 20 13:11 systemd.conf
```

And

```
ls -l /etc/modprobe.d/
```

Output:

```
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  325 Aug 15  2017 blacklist-ath_pci.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  210 Aug 15  2017 blacklist-firewire.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  697 Aug 15  2017 blacklist-framebuffer.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  583 Aug 15  2017 blacklist-rare-network.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1603 Aug 15  2017 blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  347 Aug 15  2017 iwlwifi.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  379 Oct 10  2017 mdadm.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  104 Aug 15  2017 mlx4.conf
```

And:

```
ls -l /run/modprobe.d/
```

Output:

```
ls: cannot access '/run/modprobe.d/': No such file or directory
```

Is it all about the the boot stage the configuration files are read?

---

Further reading the linked page, it seems */lib/modprobe.d* is for configuration files for the packages we install in the system. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where to place modules settings

/etc/modprobe.d

> it seems /lib/modprobe.d is for conf files for the packages we install in the system.

Yes, there are directories for software packages and site specific:

> [modprobe: use more than one config directory](https://github.com/vadmium/module-init-tools/commit/9454d710137be3799f343cc9d0f833f0802e2111)
>
> Read config files from the following directories:
>
> /run/modprobe.d   config files generated at runtime, useful e.g. for
>   compatibility     with non-standard config files (such as /etc/rc.conf in
>   Arch)
>
> /etc/modprobe.d   config files manually created by the administrator
>
> /lib/modprobe.d   config files installed by third-party packages
>
> /usr/local/lib/modprobe.d     config files during development of
>   third-party packages
>
> This scheme is the same as the one employed by udev, systemd and
>   possibly others.
>
> A follow-up patch lets files in one directory override files in
>   others, as done elsewhere.

/usr/lib/modprobe.d/ is also a thing, there's some noise about it on Red Hat and Debian bug trackers, and the Arch wiki. (Both the merged /usr proponents and opponents can have it their way!)